# How can i run Check ESA SciHub in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the list of file names covering a point or area of interest for a specified time perion from scihub. Because i use this list to get quick looks of the area, so i can check wheter it is cloudy or not.Then download the adequate files. Back to the point, i can not run it, the main reason why i cant run it is the lack of experience with python. I would be thankful if you can help. 
Aslo here is the link where you can find the source code:
https://bitbucket.org/Polarnix/check-esa-scihub/src/master/

I have tried running the program in command prompt. And yes i have download python. i tried using this command : python check_ESA_SciHub.py --help 
but i didnt work.

I have no clue what to expect due to the fact i wasnt able to run it for single time.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Do you get any error message when you try to run the script?

Comment: yes i get this error messsage: IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? I don't get that error when trying to run the script (with Python 3.7.2).

Comment: thank you for replying at all, honestly, you suprised me. And i am using the same python as you. How do you run it? can you link me a tutorial?The main reason why i have issues  is being a  beginner in python.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if running a more complex script like yours is a good starting point to learn about Python, but I won't judge.

Running a Python script is as simple as you already tried

```
python my_script.py
```

(Or on Windows you can run `py my_script.py` to use the [Python lauchner](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) which, by default, chooses the most recent Python version you have installed, to run the script)

So since you're running Python 3, the script needs to be adjusted, because with Python 3 statements like `print "Some text"` are not valid anymore (this was okay in Python 2). Instead you have to surround the text with brackets like: `print("Some text")`.

There are several places in the script which need to be modified. After the syntax is correct you should make sure all dependencies which the script need are installed. You can read about that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html). For example "urllib2" is imported and used in the script, but that module doesn't come with Python by default and therefore needs to be installed manually.

To learn all the basics of Python you can try [learnpython.org](https://www.learnpython.org/) or any other source. There are thousands of examples on around.

Comment: SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Start date/time cannot be after end date/time.")? What does this mean?

Comment: Even though that error message is pretty clear: Please read my answer again.